# How to use a method that returns boolean in ftl's <#if> statement

Tags: java, freemarker

So, in Java, you can call some methods that return `Boolean` on a `String`, for example, `string.startsWith("substring")`. I want to use this in the ftl file, but for some reason this does not work.

```
<#if string.startsWith("substring")></#if>
```

I am pretty new to ftl, I just started learning it today, but, why this does not work? In java, `if` statement accepts `Boolean`, `startsWith` method returns `Boolean`, so, what is the problem here?

Error is: `Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string`. I do not get it, how can `if` statement receive a hash?? Should not it receive a `Boolean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Java String methods are hidden in FTL. You have to instead use an FTL builtin. In your case, use

```
<#if string?starts_with("substring")></#if>
```

See [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_starts_with)

Comment: I was not avare of this hidden part. Thank you, this is what I was looking for.